# iOS + AzureSQL + web app + connection string assistance

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, azure-sql-database, connection-string

I am working on an iOS app (in swift) to send information to a SQL DB hosted on Azure. After completing the tutorial (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-ios-get-started) and downloading their iOS quickstart, I was unable to send or query the database at all. Here is the error messages I get:

> Error: Error Domain=com.Microsoft.MicrosoftAzureMobile.ErrorDomain
>   Code=-1170 "Not all operations completed successfully"
>   UserInfo={com.Microsoft.MicrosoftAzureMobile.ErrorPushResultKey=(
>       "No item was provided.",
>       "No item was provided.",
>       "No item was provided.",
>       "No item was provided.",
>       "No item was provided.",
>       "No item was provided.",
>       "No item was provided.",
>       "No item was provided.",
>       "No item was provided.",
>       "No item was provided.",
>       "No item was provided.",
>       "No item was provided.",
>       "No item was provided.",
>       "No item was provided.",
>       "No item was provided.",
>       "No item was provided.",
>       "No item was provided.",
>       "No item was provided.",
>       "No item was provided.",
>       "\n\n\n\nError\n\n\n
>
> ```
> Cannot
> POST /tables/TodoItem
> ```
>
> \n\n\n" ),
>   NSLocalizedDescription=Not all operations completed successfully}

I managed to get ahold of a cloud architect, and they mentioned that the connection string I used is incorrect (and is not the listed ADO.NET, JDBC, ODBC, PHP, GO) for swift-based apps.

Would anyone be so kind to provide the swift to web app to azure SQL Database connection string format? I don't have experience in databases or web apps, so please be descriptive with your answers!

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Easy Tables are no longer supported by Azure App Service: [Easy tables and easy APIs will be removed from Azure App Service on November 11, 2019](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/removing-easy-tables-and-easy-apis-from-azure-app-service/).

Please see the [Xamarin Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/) for the latest content. Here is the [iOS Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/hello-ios/hello-ios-quickstart?pivots=windows).

Additional information for Xamarin.iOS and the Apple Platform can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/macios/?context=xamarin/ios).

**UPDATE:**
I spoke with an Web Apps Engineer and he provided me this guidance. You can get Easy Tables to work as they are still supported. You need to do the following per this blog: [Removing Easy Tables and Easy APIs from Azure App Service](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2019/07/25/Removing-Easy-Tables-and-Easy-APIs-from-Azure-App-Services.html)

- From the SQL database in Azure portal, you can run the following query to add a table named TodoItems from Query editor (preview)

  `CREATE TABLE TodoItems
  (
    id NVARCHAR(36) PRIMARY KEY,
    createdAt DATETIMEOFFSET NOT NULL,
    updatedAt DATETIMEOFFSET,
    version TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    deleted BIT NOT NULL,
    complete BIT NOT NULL,
    text NVARCHAR(256)
  );`
- In App Service Editor or locally, click on wwwroot/tables directly to create new files, {tablename}.js and {tablename}.json where {tablename} refers to the name of the table you created in Step 1. Sample code can be found at [todoitem.js](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-quickstarts/blob/master/backend/node/TodoSample/tables/todoitem.js) and [todoitem.json](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-quickstarts/blob/master/backend/node/TodoSample/tables/todoitem.json).
- Edit the files locally and deploy the changes to Azure App Service.